# How to change Neovim font?

Tags: fonts, neovim

VIM contains a 'set guifont' option to change the font. Neovim [does not support this option](https://github.com/rogual/neovim-dot-app/issues/48), so I am wondering if it's possible to change the font Neovim uses in the Terminal?

Comment: A possible workaround: If your terminal supports it, you may be able to pass a config file or font as a CLI option on launching a new terminal.  For example with Alacritty, something like `function vim() { alacritty -o font.normal.family="Fira Code" -e nvim "$@" }`.  That way at least the change remains local to Neovim.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Change the font in your terminal emulator's preferences. Terminal programs generally can't set their own fonts. Only GUI clients like Gvim or macvim use the `set guifont` option.

Answer (score 39):

This is not for a terminal, but still it might be useful to someone.

For Neovim-Qt GUI client, you can change the font by Ctrl + mouse scroll if you put the following to `ginit.vim`:

```
let s:fontsize = 12
function! AdjustFontSize(amount)
  let s:fontsize = s:fontsize+a:amount
  :execute "GuiFont! Consolas:h" . s:fontsize
endfunction

noremap <C-ScrollWheelUp> :call AdjustFontSize(1)<CR>
noremap <C-ScrollWheelDown> :call AdjustFontSize(-1)<CR>
inoremap <C-ScrollWheelUp> <Esc>:call AdjustFontSize(1)<CR>a
inoremap <C-ScrollWheelDown> <Esc>:call AdjustFontSize(-1)<CR>a
```

For those who prefer using keyboard, there is a nice way to use numpad's `+` (`kPlus`) and `-` (`kMinus`)

```
" In normal mode, pressing numpad's+ increases the font
noremap <kPlus> :call AdjustFontSize(1)<CR>
noremap <kMinus> :call AdjustFontSize(-1)<CR>

" In insert mode, pressing ctrl + numpad's+ increases the font
inoremap <C-kPlus> <Esc>:call AdjustFontSize(1)<CR>a
inoremap <C-kMinus> <Esc>:call AdjustFontSize(-1)<CR>a
```

Obviously you can replace `Consolas` with the font you prefer.

Comment: there was no Consolas font on my system (Xubuntu 18.04) but this worked `:execute "GuiFont! DejaVu Sans Mono:h" . s:fontsize`

Answer (score 24):

How to change the font depends on how you are currently using Neovim:

## For terminal Neovim

If you use Neovim in a terminal, to change the font neovim used, you need to change the font your terminal uses. Check your terminal manual on how to change font style and font size, etc.

## For Neovim GUI client

For Neovim GUI client, you need to set the font in the file `ginit.vim`. `ginit.vim` is located in the same folder as `init.vim` or `init.lua`[^1]. Different GUI clients have different command for setting the font you use and font size. An incomplete list of GUI clients I have tried:

- [nvim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt): Use the comamnd `GuiFont` inside `ginit.vim` to change font, for example, `GuiFont Hack:h12` (suppose you have installed font Hack).
- [fvim](https://github.com/yatli/fvim): fvim is another Neovim GUI client. You can use `set guifont=Hack:12` inside `ginit.vim` to set the font that fvim uses.

[^1]: Inside Neovim, run command `:echo stdpath('config')` to show the neovim configuration directory.

Comment: It seems to me that `GuiFont` is what should be used. However nvim-qt v0.8.2 on Windows changes the font after restarting the application. I posted my workaround as an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I use Neovim-qt version on my Ubuntu18.04. But I use the same config file for my vim.

After trial-and-error, I found the way to change neovim font to FiraCode Monospace. Although you could type the command `:Guifont Fira Mono:h12` inside GUI to change the currently used font, it works only once. After you close the GUI, need to set up the font again. : (
Or you need another config file `ginit.vim` to set up GUI-related things. The same problem of setting up font for GUI, just write `GuiFont Fira Mono:h12` in `ginit.vim`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the answers in this question, the reason many scripts/plugins that works for vim/Gvim but not NeoVim (qt) is that in NeoVim, the font is defined by `Guifont` instead of `guifont`.

Answer (score 2):

At first, if you are using the 'text-mode' nvim,  just setup by your terminal(eg. putty, rxvt,...)

For nvim-qt, fnvim (GUI version nvim), here is the solution

1. Choose a font by `:set guifont=*` command.
2. Display the correct font name by `:set guifont?` command, remember when writing into config file, the `space` character should proper escape later. (For example the font name is `JetBrainsMono NFM:h10`)
3. Find your `config_path` by `:echo stdpath('config')`, for linux, it is often `~/.config`, for Windows it is often `$env:LOCALAPPDATA`
4. Setup your config file, for example, mine [lazyvim](https://www.lazyvim.org/) setup, nvim-qt version 0.2.16.1 on Windows. The config file can be one of these files

- <config_path>/nvim/ginit.lua
- <config_path>/init.lua
- <config_path>/nvim/lua/config/options.lua    (I prefer this)

edit the proper config file as

```
if vim.fn.has("gui_running") then
  -- vim.cmd("set guifont=JetBrainsMono\\ NFM:h10")
  vim.opt.guifont = "JetBrainsMono\\ NFM:h10"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i used neovim in wsl so if you asking in wsl i could help.
change the terminal font you will able to do that at list in wsl.

so download and install font of your need and cmd > properties > font and choese your font

Comment: i use terminal priview and i dont get that kind a thing

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other great answers: if you prefer to have something in lua that does all that, you could use [size-matters.nvim](https://github.com/tenxsoydev/size-matters.nvim). It's little plugin I had fun writing for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Using neovim on Windows (nvim-qt, NVIM v0.8.2), my font settings in `init.vim` not in effect after restarting the application.

As a workaround I set two different font settings in `init.vim`
e.g.

```
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\:h13
set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\:h14
```

This seems to force an explicit font change every time the application is started and yields the desired result: The second font that is set.

On Windows and Mac there's a graphical font picker `:set guifont=*`

Once a font is set, use `:set guifont?` to find out it's name. Mind escaping spaces with `\` as in the examples.

Note the difference in specifying font sizes on Windows and Linux:

```
Linux:   set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\ 14
Windows: set guifont=Source\ Code\ Pro\:h14
```