# How to change Neovim Qt font?

Tags: user-interface, settings, neovim

Created tabs (with `:tabnew` apparently) use another font than `set guifont`. How to change font of Qt GUI elements in Neovim?

[image: Neovim screenshot]

Comment: Changing the style of the GUI tabs and popupmen is not supported, currently.

Comment: Not sure if this will be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424640/824944

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Neovim font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285300/how-to-change-neovim-font)

Comment: @jdhao: No, it changes the font inside editor and doesn't change the font of tabs.

Comment: @nabn: No, the same as above

Comment: You may just disable the GUI tabline and use the TUI tabline. The TUI tabline use the font you set via `GuiFont` command. It seems that GUI Tabline does not respect that option?