# How do you change the font size in neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

I only case about the font size, I want nothing to do with the font other than its size `set guifont` makes me put in a font, therefor its useless to me.

Update: all of the answers here weren't what I was asking for but I gave up on trying to fix it and moved on to using vim on Cmder.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3104

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Neovim font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285300/how-to-change-neovim-font)

Comment: Your system? Your terminal? Without all this info, how do you suppose people are going to answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

For nvim-qt used in Windows, the following command works after nvim-qt has started:

```
execute join(["GuiFont! ", split(GuiFont, ":")[0], ":h14"], "")
```

With your font size in place of 14.

To set the font size at start, you have to use ginit.vim instead of init.vim, since init.vim starts before the GUI is loaded. Location of ginit.vim is C:\Users[User]\AppData\Local\nvim.